# How can i multiply select option data attributes with input text area values?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i multiply select option data attributes with input text area values?

```
<select>
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option date-price="2" value="1">Sausage</option>
    <option date-price="4" value="2">Potato</option>
    <option date-price="6" value="2">Pickle</option>
</select> 
<input name="quantity">
<div id="total">??</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? BTW, I guess `date-price` should be `data-price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the price as value field, you should try something like that:

```
let price = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
let quantity = document.getElementsByName('quantity')[0].value;
let total = price * quantity;

document.getElementById('total').innerHtml = total;
```

If you don't want to change the value of the option element;

```
let select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
let price = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.price;
let quantity = document.getElementsByName('quantity')[0].value;
let total = price * quantity;

document.getElementById('total').innerHtml = total;
```

The last solution allows you to get the data attribute "price" from the currently selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function calculate(event) {
  let select = document.getElementById('select');
  var selectValue = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.price);

  let input = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  if(input && selectValue) {
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = input * selectValue;
  }
}
```

```html
    <select id="select">
      <option value="0" disabled >Select</option>
      <option data-price="2" value="1">Sausage</option>
      <option data-price="4" value="2">Potato</option>
      <option data-price="6" value="2">Pickle</option>
  </select> 
  <input name="quantity" id="quantity">
  <div id="total">??</div>

  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```